# Estimate probability density from cumulative fraction

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Can I "backward" estimate the probability density by mutate function in dplyr?

```
x <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1)
df <- as.data.frame(x)  
df %>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
cs <- cusum(x)
```

then x equals

```
c(cs[1], diff(cs))
```